# How to creat data frame row by row and name the data frames meanwhile in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is the original data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, 3),
  B = c("TEST", "YEAR", "TELL"),
  C = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
```

Expected three data frames as below:

```
TEST <- data.frame(df[1,])
YEAR <- data.frame(df[2,])
TELL <- data.frame(df[3,])
```

How to generate the expected data frames easily in R (because I had a few hundred rows of the original matrix)?

Answer (score 2):

This is generally not an ideal solution to add a lot of objects in the global environment, I would suggest to keep those in a list. To do so, you can use `asplit`:

```r
list_df <- setNames(asplit(df, 1), df$B)
```

But if you prefer to have those rows as singular objects in the global environment, then you can use `list2env`:

```r
list2env(list_df, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: This doesn't create data frames, neither this solution nor OPs indicated output.

Comment: Yep, I tried the code. The class of list_df is "array", and the class of list_df$TEST is "array" as well. I used a similar way to generate a list that stored three data frames:
 new_data <- split(df, df$B)
but it is not what I want, I do not want three matrices stored in one list.

Answer (score 2):

From the given data frame `df` we create a list with names of the data frames. For this we use base R `split` (in contrast to `group_split` from `dplyr`, here the names remain). Then we use `walk` and iterate over the names of the `my_list`. For each name (.x), `assign` is used to create a variable in the global environment with the same name and assign it the corresponding data frame from `my_list`.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

my_list <- df %>% 
  split(.$B)

walk(names(my_list), ~ assign(.x, my_list[[.x]], envir = .GlobalEnv))

TELL
TEST
YEAR
```

output:

```
> TELL
  A    B    C
3 3 TELL TRUE
> TEST
  A    B    C
1 1 TEST TRUE
> YEAR
  A    B     C
2 2 YEAR FALSE

> class(TELL)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consinder a piped version relying on `lapply()`

```r
lapply(seq(nrow(df)), FUN = \(i) data.frame(df[i, ])) |>
  setNames(object = _, nm = df$B) |>
  list2env(x = _, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

which results in
[image]

A nested alternative using `split()`:

```r
list2env(setNames(split(df, seq(nrow(df))), df$B), .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Learned a lot! Nested alternative is truly concise